# AppInsights End-to-end transaction details does not show more than 1000 requests

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to use AppInsights in order to analyze the build performance. So, my events are not actual requests, but I send them to AppInsights as `RequestTelemetry` in order to benefit from the end-to-end transaction details view.

The problem is that this view shows 1000 events at most and so if I have more than that the output is confusing garbage.

Is there way to increase the count of events to be shown?

Comment: Hi mark, could you please attach an screenshots of it? and also provides the code snippets to send events via RequestTelemetry. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I will try and publish the project on GitHub. Then I will be able to direct you to the respective code.